# Subring of $\Bbb F_{125}$ generated by ${1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I have a field $\Bbb F_{125}$ which is

$$\Bbb F_{125}=\frac{\Bbb F_5[X]}{\langle X^3+X+1\rangle}$$

I have been asked to find the subring generated by the multiplicative identity of this field. I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: Start doing the ring operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication) with a bunch (zero or more) $1$s: $1+1$, $-1$, $(1+1)+1)$, $(1+1)(1+1+1+1+1+1)$ et cetera. Which elements will you generate this way?

Answer (score 3):

The subring must contain the identity $1$ and must be closed under addition and multiplication. In particular it must contain $1, 1+1=2, 1+1+1=3, 1+1+1+1=4, 1+1+1+1+1=0$. Can you show that these elements already form a subring?